# ReactJS/JestJS/Enzyme: How to test graphql() function used in compose()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-apollo

This is how I'm testing a very simple reactJS component with react-apollo via jestJS. I'm also using the coverage function of jest.

But the coverage shows me, that I'm missing to test the line `options: (props) => ({` in the `graphql()`.

How should I do this correctly?

**Example.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { graphql, compose } from 'react-apollo'
import { getPostsQuery } from './graphql/query'

export class Example extends Component {
  render () {
    const { data } = this.props
    const { getPosts, loading } = data

    return (
      <div id="article">
        {
          getPosts.map(post => {
            return (<div>{post.content}</div>)
          })
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default compose(
  graphql(
    getPostsQuery, {
      options: (props) => ({
        variables: {
          articleId: props.articleId
        }
      })
    }
  )
)(Example)
```

**Unit test**

```
import React from 'react'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import { Example } from './components/Example'

describe('<Example />', () => {
  it('should render #article element', () => {
    wrapper = shallow(<Example data={data} />)
    expect(wrapper.find('#article')).toHaveLength(1)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see your test does not test the apollo bit right. Right now you are testing if React is able to render a div. That is because you are importing the component only and not the enhanced version of it. If you wanna cover everything you have to `import Example from './components/Example'`. But then you'll have another problem about mocking the apollo server. Here is a good article on that topic https://medium.com/@carlos_42328/mocking-api-responses-with-react-apollo-11eb4610debe

Another option is to use Jest's `coveragePathIgnorePatterns` option like so:

**Example.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { graphql, compose } from 'react-apollo'
import { getPostsQuery } from './graphql/query'

export default class Example extends Component {
  render () {
    const { data } = this.props
    const { getPosts, loading } = data

    return (
      <div id="article">
        {
          getPosts.map(post => {
            return (<div>{post.content}</div>)
          })
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**ExampleComposed.js**

```
import Example from './Example';

export default compose(
  graphql(
    getPostsQuery, {
      options: (props) => ({
        variables: {
          articleId: props.articleId
        }
      })
    }
  )
)(Example)
```

And then in your `package.json` file

```
{
  "jest": {
    "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "./node_modules",
      "./path/to/file/ExampleComposed.js"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can I exclude the complete compose part from the coverage?

Comment: You can't ignore only part of a file but if you extract the composing into a separate one you'll be able to do it via http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#coveragepathignorepatterns-array-string

Comment: How do I extract it?

Comment: You still export `Example` but you export it as `default`. Then create a function that imports it and use the compose. I edited my answer. Check it above.